# Java communication with JavaDB classNotFoundException

Tags: java, derby, classnotfoundexception, javadb

I'm trying to make a Java program that can communicate with JavaDB. I've made the Database class, started a server and made a tiny client program to check if they would communicate.

The program crashes when i try to run it, giving a class not found exception at the line where i try to set the database driver. I googled it and found that this error appears if derbyclient.jar and derby.jar are not found in the classpath. I also read that the scripts setNetworkClientCP and setNetworkServerCP found in the db directory would set these in the classpath. I found the scripts, ran them, and checked to make sure the classpath got updated, but i still get the same error. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

EDIT: SOLVED - i just realized that i need to include the derbyclient.jar in the NetBeans project library.

Comment: Are you using any IDE to run your code? How are you setting the classpath? Also, please paste the error your getting(the trace).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using NetBeans and the built in JavaDB. I set the classpath by using the scripts that i mentioned above, and upon checking the classpath i found these entries:

1. %DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbyclient.jar;
2. %DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derby.jar;
3. %DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbytools.jar;
4. %DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbynet.jar;

The Error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
at Database.<init>(Database.java:14)
at TestKlient.main(TestKlient.java:8)
```